# Block port for integration testing

Tags: java, junit, connection, block, false-positive

Is there a way to block a port for running Java application, to emulate connectivity failures, for false-positive tests:

- Block connection to **DB** to emulate **DB failure
- Block connection to **JMS** to emulate JMS failure
- Block connection to **Internet** to emulate behavior in standalone mode

I am talking here about integration testing, with standalone jetty server, which is running on the same machine but in a different JVM. So I am looking for a more generic mechanism for port blocking, than those of a Mock frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

A mocking framework, e.g. [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) can be used to test such cases. e.g. Using mockito, you can mock a `DBConnection` class, so that when you try to invoke method to run SQL query, you can make that method throw `ConnectionException` or `timeout` to test how your application responds to such cases.

Comment: I am talking about integration, not unit tests. 
Mockito is more of a solution for unit testing from my point of view.
Also I am testing with standalone server, which is running on the same machine but in a different JVM.

Comment: @anton_oparin for an integration test as well, I think that Mockito is  very usable. If you are using Dependency injection in your code ( formally or informally), then it is very easy to use Mockito for Integration testing. You can simply initialize classes with mocked dependency rather than say actual DBConnection. Really simplifies simulating such cases.